# Do automated reloaders stack?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

My current game is going very well and I have a more powerful arsenal of weapons than in any of my previous games (2x burst laser, breach bomb mk II and anti-bio beam). I also have one automated reloader augmentation already, and now I just found a shop that sells a second one.

Do two of these augmentations stack, or would I be wasting scraps by buying the second one?

And if they stack, do they stack multiplicatively or additive with each other and any other factors like crew experience that decrease reload time?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes. Any augmentation you can buy twice, stacks. If it doesn't stack you will be unable to buy it in a shop, and you'll get scrap instead of it as an event reward.

More precisely, any augmentation with `<stackable>true</stackable>` in the game resources is stackable and can be bought more than once, and the Automated Re-loader (`AUTO_COOLDOWN`) is so flagged.

[It's known that Scrap Recovery Arms stack additively rather than multiplicatively](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85982/whats-the-effect-of-having-more-than-one-scrap-recovery-arm); other stackable augmentations likely work the same way.

Comment: "Whether stacking is additive or multiplicative is as of yet unknown." - Not Anymore!

Comment: This is to the user's benefit anyway. Taking 15% of 15% of 100% yields 72.25%, while 15%+15% is 70% fire delay. It's also a heck of a lot easier to do from a coding perspective.

Comment: Automated reloaders stack additively but they influence charge *rate* rather than charge time. So 2 reloaders is not 80% charge time, it's 1.2 charge rate meaning 83% charge time. Crew training however affects charge time directly, so level 2 crew + 2 reloaders is 0.8 / 1.2 = 66% of the weapon's nominal charge time.